# how to display header in a page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to display the header of a particular theme. I have done by writing this code in the template like below :

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name:CLIENT LIST
*/
get_header("header1");
?>
```

Is this correct ? I have named the file as header1.php. I have already header.php.I wanted to make another header file so i named it as header1.php.

Comment: If you already did this, what is your question? Does it work or not?

Comment: it is not working...it is taking the previous header file itself..

Comment: rename the file as header-header1.php

Comment: thanksss ...its working:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_header) shows you the correct approach:

```
<?php get_header( $name ); ?>
```

> **$name**
>   *(string) (optional)* Calls for header-name.php.
>   Default: *None*

So, name your file `header-something.php` and call it with `get_header( 'something' );`